# R: Percentage stack bar chart in plotly

Tags: r, charts, plotly

I have a dataset like below

```
City<-c("X","Y","Z","X","Z","X","Y")
House_Unit_Id<-c("H1","H2","H3","H4","H5","H6","H7")
Adult<-c(50,100,60,40,50,80,60)
Child<-c(40,0,40,20,50,20,30)
Baby<-c(10,0,0,40,0,0,10)
data<-data.frame(City,House_Unit_Id,Adult,Child,Baby)

 City House_Unit_Id Adult   Child   Baby
  X       H1         50      40     10
  Y       H2        100       0      0
  Z       H3         60      40      0
  X       H4         40      20     40
  Z       H5         50      50      0
  X       H6         80      20      0
  Y       H7         60      30     10
```

I need a percentage column stack chart like below
[image: What I need]

I tried the below code but the required output is not appearing as a percentage stack bar chart.

```
Chart <- plot_ly(data,x = ~City, y = ~Adult, type = 'bar',name= 'Adult') %>% 
  add_trace(y = ~Child, name = 'Child') %>% 
  add_trace(y = ~Baby, name = 'Baby') %>% 
  layout(yaxis = list(title = 'Percentage (%)'),barmode = "stack")
```

This is what I currently get
[image: What I currently get]

I could not find any answers for this type of chart for plotly package in R. Can anyone please help me with this?

Comment: fig 2.24 in [plotly book](https://cpsievert.github.io/plotly_book/bars-histograms.html). Did you try reading the documentation? Also, the columns you use in plotly are not present in the data you provide.Please add `dput` of your actual data

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The following code gives you the plot you describe, with the total number of type (Adult/Children/Baby) in each City in the hovertext (If you also want it on the plot itself you can try add_annotations)

```
  City<-c("X","Y","Z","X","Z","X","Y")
  House_Unit_Id<-c("H1","H2","H3","H4","H5","H6","H7")
  Adult<-c(50,100,60,40,50,80,60)
  Child<-c(40,0,40,20,50,20,30)
  Baby<-c(10,0,0,40,0,0,10)
  data<-data.frame(City,House_Unit_Id,Adult,Child,Baby)

  library(plyr)
  # Changing the data frame before plotting ... there is propably an easier way to do this!
  newdata <- ldply(3:5,function(n){tempdata <- data[,c(1,n)]
                               colnames(tempdata)[2] <- "Number"
                               tempdata$type <- colnames(data[n])
                               return(tempdata)})
  newdata <- ddply(newdata,.(City,type),summarize,Number=sum(Number))
  # Total for each city
  datatotal <- ddply(newdata,~City,summarize,n=sum(Number))
  # Merge the data frames together
  newdata <- merge(newdata,datatotal)
  # Calc the percentages
  newdata$perc <- newdata$Number/newdata$n

plot_ly(newdata,x = ~City, y = ~perc*100, type = 'bar',color = ~type,text=~Number,hoverinfo = 'text') %>% 
   layout(yaxis = list(title = 'Percentage (%)'),barmode = "stack")
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you want stacked percentage barplots across "City" not "House_Unit_Id", there are two things you can do. Either use the proportions you now have and create a combination of stacked and grouped barplot, where you are stacking by House_Unit_Id and grouping by City. Currently, I don't think the plotly package (correct me if I am wrong) is capable of doing this. You can use ggplot to do this.

However, if you really want to only compare percentages across City, you should aggregate the *counts* in Adult, Child and Baby with something like this:

```
newData = aggregate(. ~ City, data = data, FUN = sum)
```

Then calculate the proportions *by City*. After that, you can plot the percentages as stacked bars for each City.

```
Chart <- plot_ly(newData, x = ~City, y = ~Adult, type = 'bar', name= 'Adult') %>% 
  add_trace(y = ~Child, name = 'Child') %>% 
  add_trace(y = ~Baby, name = 'Baby') %>% 
  layout(yaxis = list(title = 'Percentage (%)'), barmode = "stack")
```

This will work if you aggregate your *counts* data by City and calculate the proportions for each City.

Comment: @useR- Hi, Sorry if my sample data was confusing which I have edited with more detail now. What I really need is that I have calculated Adult, child, Baby proportion for each household (That's why row-wise total is100). Now I need a percent stack bar chart across the City for comparison.

Comment: @Jessie Ok. So the "House_Unit_Id" is a very important information you have left out in your question.